# Airflow operator to run multiple Big Query Job

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, airflow, operator-keyword

I'm trying to run an IF ELSE statement in Airflow that involves delete and insert of dataset based on the what is the current month.

I have tried to use BigQueryInsertJobOperator but it doesn't allow to run multiple queries in 1 task：

```
BQ_INSERT_QUERY = '''
    DECLARE current_year STRING;
    DECLARE past_year STRING;
    
SET (current_year, past_year) = (SELECT AS STRUCT
     CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE()) AS STRING) AS current_year,
     CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AS STRING) AS past_year);
    
IF EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE()) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN

DELETE FROM `data-pipeline.MAIN.Main_Table`
WHERE CAST(column1 AS STRING) like CONCAT('%', current_year)
    
INSERT INTO `data-pipeline.MAIN.Main_Table` (column1,column2,column3)
SELECT column1,column2,column3
FROM `data-pipeline.MAIN.Hold_Table`
WHERE CAST(column1 AS STRING) like CONCAT('%', current_year) 

ELSE
    
DELETE FROM `data-pipeline.MAIN.Main_Table`
WHERE CAST(column1 AS STRING) like CONCAT('%', past_year);

INSERT INTO `data-pipeline.MAIN.Main_Table` (column1,column2,column3)
SELECT column1,column2,column3
FROM `data-pipeline.MAIN.Hold_Table`
WHERE CAST(column1 AS STRING) like CONCAT('%', past_year);
    
END IF; 
    
'''

insert_target_table = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id='daily_insert_target_table',
    project_id='data-pipeline',
    location='asia-southeast1',
    configuration={
        'query': {
            'query': [BQ_INSERT_QUERY],
            'useLegacySql': False
        }
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use the [@task.branch decorator or the BranchPythonOperator](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-branch-operator). You can use that to choose which downstream task to run based on the logic in the branch.